# is there a faster way to extract unique values from object collection?

Tags: java, collections

I have a method to extract the values from an object collection that is a employee information:

```
public class Employee
{
    public String AREA;
    public String EMPLOYEE_ID;
    public String EMPLOYEE_NAME;
}
```

I'd like to get all the distinct Areas I did what I thought would be the easier, just check if the ArrayList contains the value, if not the add it, it takes 187ms to complete, :

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ArrayList<String> distinct_areas = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.employeeTress.length; i++)
    {
        if (!distinct_areas.contains(this.employeeTress[i].AREA))
            distinct_areas.add(this.employeeTress[i].AREA);
    }
    String[] unique = new String[distinct_areas.size()];
    distinct_areas.toArray(unique);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
```

then I thought to do it differently to see if it gets faster, sorting the array then check only the last item if its different then add it, and its a little bit faster, it takes 121ms to complete:

```
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String[] vs = new String[this.employeeTress.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.employeeTress.length; i++)
    {
        vs[i] = this.employeeTress[i].AREA;
    }
    Arrays.sort(vs);
    ArrayList<String> vsunique = new ArrayList<String>();
    vsunique.add(vs[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < vs.length; i++)
    {
        if (!vsunique.get(vsunique.size()-1).equals(vs[i]))
        {
            vsunique.add(vs[i]);
        }
    }
    String[] uni = new String[vsunique.size()];
    vsunique.toArray(uni);
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
```

I'm new to Java I'd like to know a better way to do this. 
*Note, this code should work in android gingerbread API LVL 10
regards.

Comment: Use a `Set` instead of a `List`. Also, I would not worry for this *performance improvement* until it demonstrates to be a real bottleneck in the application.

Comment: The only types in Java that should be ALL CAPS are `final static` primitives or `enum`s.

Comment: @Dukeling And that includes the name of the JAVA language itself :))

Comment: sorry for the all caps fields that class is a copy paste from an extraction form a json structure that has all caps fields coming from an ORM with automated table creation from Oracle database, in other words i didn't type them.

Comment: If this is an ORM, can't you just do something to get the distinct areas through the ORM?

Comment: since the wireless signal is very weak I'm trying to reduce the network traffic as much as possible and since the information is already there after I pull all active employees once. this information will be stored locally to reduce network traffic even more.

Comment: to be honest I found similar questions but for some reason they didnt work, I thought that was because it was for java in general not for android, even that it was not the reason, thats why I added android tags to my question, so why were those removed?

Comment: If you want to do add() and contains() quickly then use HashSet. BUT if you want to do quickly add(),contains() and in addition get(key) then use HashMap. Note that HashSet is just a wrapper around HashMap so speed is identical. The only difference that HashSet does not have quick get() whereas HashMap has its get(key)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to get or count the distinct areas in the employee list, you can use a set of strings.  I'm changing the variable names to match Java standards. You can get the count afterwards.  ideally, these would be lazy methods.

### Imperative Code

```
public Set<String> areas(final List<Employee> employees) {
    Set<String> areas = new HashSet<>();
    for(final Employee employee: employees) {
        areas.add(employee.getArea());
    }
    return areas;
}
```

### Functional Code (Google Guava)

```
public Set<String> areas(final List<Employee> employees) {
    return Sets.newHashSet(
        Lists.transform(employees, new Function<Employee, String>() {
            public String apply(Employee e) {
                return e.getArea();
            }
        }));
}
```

### Lambdas (Java 8)

```
public Set<String> areas(final List<Employee> employees) {
    return new HashSet<String>(employees.map(e => e.getArea()));
}
```

Comment: Imperative form using HashSet is much faster than checking if item is already in the collection. thank you.

Comment: That's because the JRE is doing the same thing.  The other versions simply remove the explicit looping. They don't buy you that much snce this isn't a lazy problem; you need to compute the entire thing.  Still, you should consider other ways of storing the data. A relational database could store your employees, and with appropriate indexing, the db could work extremely fast.  I did fix a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Insert all employees into the `HashSet`. From the definition of `Set`, they will be all unique.

```
Set<Employee> unique = new HashSet<Employee>(Arrays.asList(employeeTress));
// unique.toArray() if needed
```

If you want `Employee` objects to be considered equal when they have the same `AREA`, you need to [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) override the `equals()` method in `Employee` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Set` to do this, as others have already stated, but if you want items to be considered equal when they have the same `AREA` then you'll need to override the `equals` method in your `Employee` object to make it compare itself to others based on that variable.

You need to know a few things before just overidding the equals method.  There's a discussion about it here:
[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Just use HashSet, it will **ONLY add unique elements to the HashSet**.

The `objectOfHashSet.add(Object)` function of HashSet will return `true on successful` addition of the object,

```
Set<Employee> hs = new HashSet<Employee>();

    if(!hs.add(i2)){
      // do some operation here
    }
```

You will also need to override the `equals method` here.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Employee))
            return false;

        // HERE PERFORM YOUR CHECK
        if("Employee.NAME".isequals(obj.NAME))
        {return true;}
    }
```

Also make sure that the `hashCode() of the key objects` that you put into the collection never changes while the object is in the collection. The best way to ensure this is to make your `keys immutable`.

Comment: In fact, the `Set` should be to hold the `Employee` data instead of the current array OP's using.